# bootstrap adding image in a row stretch the logo?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm try to use the bootstrap 4 to build a website. When I try to add a logo image and a text in the header, but the image gets stretched as the following:
[image]

Here is my html,

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img alt="logo" src="img/udacity.png" id="header-logo" class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 img-fluid"/>
      <h1 class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-11" id="header-text">Text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I tried to set the height in my css file, but it cannot be set exactly as the height-size of the **Text**, and it cannot work responsively even use percent. How can I fix this this?

Meanwhile, I have also set the row border using `.row {border-bottom: 10px solid #000;}` but nothing shows up, it seems I cannot override the row class?

I'm using safari and here's the style properties after I click inspect element on the logo inside safari:

```
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-top-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
display: block;
flex-basis: 8.333333015441895%;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 233px;
line-height: 24px;
max-width: 8.333333015441895%;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-top: 8px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 45px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `img` and `h1` tags are direct children of `.row`, which is a flex container.  As such, the image tag is being stretched to match the height of all siblings.

Simple fix here is to just wrap both in a `.col-12` (assuming you want this pair of elements to span the full width of the container).

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img alt="logo" src="img/udacity.png" id="header-logo" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-11">
          <h1 id="header-text">Yutian Wu</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/monners/pen/rprGpa?editors=1100

Comment: So you mean that putting them directly into the flex container will remain the height of the image which is the height of all siblings?

Comment: The heights will be normalised across all elements within the flex container (by default) that are in the same row.  The flex-container (`.row`) is never supposed to contain anything other than `.col-` elements, as it's using flex to fluidly adjust the relative widths and heights of the child elements.
Demo: https://codepen.io/monners/pen/rprGpa

Comment: I'm sorry, though the height has changed but after changing it, why they are not align in the same line now?

Comment: Ah, that's because the container structure isn't quite correct.  I've updated my answer to reflect how this should be laid out properly for the bootstrap grid.

Comment: No problem.  Maybe spend a bit of time reading the bootstrap docs.  The markup requirements can be quite specific.

Comment: Last question... Why sometimes when I edit css style in separate css file, for example, I want to change the style of h2 using `h2#id {...}` doesn't take effect, but after adding `h2{}` above it even with nothing in the curly-bracket, the style got override?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Maybe post another separate question with an example of what you're doing (although the question has probably already been answered, so be sure to do a search first).  Chances are you're either not targeting the right ID, or there's a specificity problem (although the latter is unlikely, given you're using the ID selector, which has very high specificity)